# AngularJS watching attribute changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a directive named errorMarker for showing error messages on input control. The problem I am facing is that, first time attribute changes are getting detected and next time it doesn't detect. I have created a fiddle where you will see a text field and a button. Directive is applied on the text field.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" error-marker error-message="{{error}}" size="20">
```

Also there is a button on click of which the model value is checked and error property on scope is set. Once the error is set the textfield border become red. 
Now if you remove the model value and click the button, border doesn't become red. The reason is attribute change is not getting detected. I am wondering why the change is not getting detected because I am also setting the attribute value to blank from the directive.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FvLQN/1245/

Comment: Why don't you just use build-in validation capabilities? What you have now is pretty bad (things like `element.removeClass('required-field');`).

Comment: The directive is far more complex and we are doing validation using meta-view provided by the API. Here I have simplified the directive to demo the issue I am facing.

Comment: It can be complex but you should still use proper validation API's Angular provides. Things like `element.addClass('required-field')`, `element.on('keydown', removeErrorStyle);`, `$attr.$observe('errorMessage', function () {` - you don't need it, it just makes directive look like one big anti-pattern. For API validation use async validators.

Comment: Can you describe how modifying an element inside a directive is anti pattern and how built in validators do it then  ?

Comment: I called anti-pattern because you don't need to set and remove those classes, as well as binding additional events. Basically entire errorMarker doesn't make sense to me. Again, using proper Angular validation would solve it easily. But of course, you can build custom solution too.

Comment: Can you tell me how angular validators apply and remove styles?

Comment: @dfsq I don't think its anti-pattern. If some need to create custom directives and need to add/remove few attr according to the feature than the person can do it. Angular has given the feature for $observer and I think the que is trying to explain that only.

Comment: Let's not discuss anti patterns, what about the observer behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting **error** variable to "*Invalid Name*" everytime, so the value doesn't change and your function is not triggered.

Try this:

```
$scope.error= "Invalid Name " + $scope.name;
```

Comment: From within the directive I am resetting the attribute to blank. $attr.$set('errorMessage', '');